# merging sites and redirecting old urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have merged 2 sites and have to organise redirects from the domain that is now not in use.

The domain aquarestaurantblackheath.co.uk redirects fine, but not the old  urls from that domain.

Any suggestions. see my code...

Working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$  "http\:\/\/www\.aquabarandgrill\.co\.uk\/section\/3\/1\/restaurant\-blackheath" [R=301,L]
```

Not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^section\/8\/1\/location$ "http\:\/\/www\.aquabarandgrill\.co\.uk\/section\/10\/1\/restaurant" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^section\/6\/1\/wines$ "http\:\/\/www\.aquabarandgrill\.co\.uk\/section\/8\/1\/food\-wine\-blackheath" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^section\/7\/1\/reservations$ "http\:\/\/www\.aquabarandgrill\.co\.uk\/section\/3\/1\/restaurant\-blackheath" [R=301,L]
```

---

The entire htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aquabarandgrill.co.uk [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine on
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
RewriteRule ^(.*).php/(.*) $1.php?$2

## Bromley old site REDIRECTS (PERMANANT 301) ##

RewriteRule ^Home.php?id=Menus/?$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/2/1/restaurant-bromley/ [L,R=301,NC]

#
## Deafult character encoding UTF-8 / ISO-8859-1
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.aquabarandgrill\.co\.uk\/section\/3\/1\/restaurant\-blackheath" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aquabrasseriecroydon\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.aquabrasseriecroydon\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.aquabarandgrill\.co\.uk\/section\/4\/1\/restaurant\-croydon" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/?|section/7/1/reservations)$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/3/1/restaurant-blackheath [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC] 
RewriteRule ^section\/8\/1\/location$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/10/1/restaurant [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^section\/6\/1\/wines$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/8/1/food-wine-blackheath [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try the following rules:</strike>

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/?|section/7/1/reservations)$  http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/3/1/restaurant-blackheath [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC]    
RewriteRule ^section/8/1/location$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/10/1/restaurant [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^section/6/1/wines$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/8/1/food-wine-blackheath [R=301,L]
```

---

### EDIT

After seeing the whole htaccess file, remove everything in there, and replace the whole file with the following piece of code:

```
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/?|section/7/1/reservations)$  http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/3/1/restaurant-blackheath [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC]    
RewriteRule ^section/8/1/location$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/10/1/restaurant [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aquarestaurantblackheath\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^section/6/1/wines$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/8/1/food-wine-blackheath [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php/(.*) $1.php?$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, the domain redirect works ok with that, but not the urls.

Comment: @Puzzel Can you provide some recent lines from the apache logs?

Comment: here we go

    [Thu Sep 24 23:56:00 2015] [error] [client 80.26.82.82] File does not  exist: /home/bvistaftppass/public_html/templates/aqua-panels/images/icon_element_next.png, referer: http://www.aquarestaurantblackheath.co.uk/section/6/1/wines
    [Thu Sep 24 23:56:00 2015] [error] [client 80.26.82.82] File does not exist: /home/bvistaftppass/public_html/templates/aqua-panels/templatesource/menus/superfish/css/superfish-navbar-selective.css, referer: http://www.aquarestaurantblackheath.co.uk/section/6/1/wines

Comment: It seems like you have some other rewrite rules interfering with the redirects.

Comment: it wont accept any code back in my reply with 4 spaces

Comment: @Puzzel Put them online on pastie etc website, and put the link.

Comment: @anubhava are you able to have a look at this ?

Comment: @Puzzel Updated the reply above.

Comment: they work ! thank you.

However these urls extensions don't
    /section/5/1/menus-restaurants-backheath‬
    /Home.php?id=SundayLunch

Comment: @Puzzel Readd the `RewriteRule ^Home.p..` rule. I think it got deleted with the rest of them

Comment: thanks, this the one i'm having trouble with 

    RewriteRule ^Home\.php?id=Book/?$ http://www.aquabarandgrill.co.uk/section/2/1/restaurant-bromley [R=301,L]

Comment: @Puzzel Read about query string manipulation here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString